# Instantiating a 3D array in C++ using parameters

Tags: c++, arrays

Sorry if this is a noob question, but I'm currently learning C++. I have a function that takes in several parameters - I would like to use those parameters when creating a 3D int array.

```
void* testFunction(int countX, int countY, int countZ)
{
    const int NX = countX;
    const int NY = countY;
    const int NZ = countZ;

    int* data_out = new int*[NX][NY][NZ]; 
    // The above line throws the error on "NY" - expression must
    // have a constant value
}
```

From various posts I've learned that you must allocate the array first but I guess I'm doing that wrong? How do you properly initialize a multidimensional array. Also, why does the initialization require a pointer?

Comment: Ideally you should use a 1 dimensional `vector` or `unique_ptr<T[]>` and fake the three dimensions using math.

Comment: @MichaelO.Your suggestion still throws the same "expression must have a constant value" error. EDIT: The "const int NZ - countZ" was a type - I edited the post to have the proper "=".

Comment: Short answer: *You can't do this*.  Long answer: *You shouldn't do this*.  Arrays are the wrong tool, because they do not track their own size.  See NathanOliver's comment.

Comment: @NathanOliver do any of you know where I can find a simple example that illustrates this concept?

Comment: @Roka545 see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902648/c-representing-a-3d-array-in-a-1d-array

Answer (score 2):

To explain the error: C++ requires a name of a type in its `new` operator. A name of a type cannot have runtime dimensions, because all types in C++ are static (determined at compilation time).

For example, this allocates 3 elements of type `int[4][5]`:

```
new int[3][4][5];
```

Another example: this allocates NX elements of type `int[4][5]`:

```
new int[NX][4][5];
```

An incorrect example: this would allocate NX elements of type `int[NY][NZ]`, if C++ had support for "dynamic" types:

```
new int[NX][NY][NZ];
```

---

To allocate a 3-dimensional array, or something that looks like it, you can use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> my_3D_array;
... // initialization goes here
my_3D_array[2][2][2] = 222; // whatever you want to do with it
```

To make the syntax less verbose, and streamline the initialization, use `typedef` (or here `using`, which is the same):

```
using int_1D = std::vector<int>;    // this is a 1-dimensional array type
using int_2D = std::vector<int_1D>; // this is a 2-dimensional array type
using int_3D = std::vector<int_2D>; // this is a 3-dimensional array type
int_3D data(NX, int_2D(NY, int_1D(NZ))); // allocate a 3-D array, elements initialized to 0
data[2][2][2] = 222;
```

If you want to return this array from your function, you should declare it; you cannot just return a `void` pointer to the `data` variable. Here is a syntax of a declaration:

```
using int_1D = std::vector<int>;
using int_2D = std::vector<int_1D>;
using int_3D = std::vector<int_2D>;
int_3D testFunction(int countX, int countY, int countZ)
{
    int_3D data(...);
    ...
    return data;
}
```

That is, instead of using `new`, just use `std::vector<whatever>` as if it were any other type.